# Modal Indeterminate Progress Ring implementation in winjs

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, progress-bar, modal-dialog, winjs

I am trying to implement "Modal Indeterminate Progress Ring " which will block any user activity. What i am able to achieve is a progress bar which is non modal using the following code snippet :

`var progress = document.createElement("progress");

    progress.className = "win-ring win-large";

    progress.id = "progressRing";
    document.getElementById("section").appendChild(progress);`

Any suggestions what i am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar does not force a "modal state" automatically. It's up to you to create a user experience that is "modal" and then uses the [indeterminate progress ring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465469.aspx) to show the user that the application is busy and cannot be used right now.

[image: Busy image]

As shown in the documentation:

> Disable interaction during the task by disabling controls in the app
>   bar and ignoring input in the content area.

Your code is responsible for "disabling" the application appropriately during the busy state.